# Add prerequisites in installshield

Tags: installshield, prerequisites, installshield-2010

I am new in installshield I have installshield 2010 and want to build basic msi for vs2010 wpf project with sql server 2008 r2 express I found .prq file for sql server 2008 R2 and copied that file into "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2010\SetupPrerequisites" this folder but when i run installshield my sql prq file not showing in "Installation Requirement" to check the checkbox and select prq's in my msi project

I tried to search on google but not getting right way Please help me ...

Comment: It should work. But in your case - do you sure that this prq is correct and wasn't corrupted?

Comment: @Igor Shenderchuk Thanks for the reply. Yes might be you are correct but see there are near about 30-40 .prq file in "SetupPrerequisites" folder for different-different culture (language file) but that prerequisites also not display in "Installation Requirement" and that prerequisites are provided by installshield own. so i think there is may be some other reason please help me if you have any idea about it.

Comment: If you create Basic MSI project, you will see `Redistributables` instead `Installation Requirement`. Could you clarify that?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools -> Options. A dialog will pop up and select the Prerequisites tab. Then you can make sure the location of the prerequisites folder that it is checking is the one that your prerequisite is in.